# keydown event doesn't work

Tags: jquery, events, controller, handler

i want make player controller for my 1st game in jquery but something is wrong. Can you help me, please?

```
$('canvas').keydown(function(e) {
    alert('in function');
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {//37 - strzalka w lewo
        moveleft();
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {//39 - strzalka w prawo
        moveright();
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {//40 - strzalka w dol
        movedown();
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {//38 - strzalka w gore
         moveup();
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {//32 - spacja

    }
});

function moveup() {
    gracz.speedY -= 1; 
}

function movedown() {
    gracz.speedY += 1; 
}

function moveleft() {
    gracz.speedX -= 1;
}

function moveright() {
    gracz.speedX += 1;
}
```

when i press arrows, event handler doesn't work

Comment: Retrieving key-related events on a `canvas` is unreliable at best. Use a parent element of the `canvas` instead, or even the `window`, eg: https://jsfiddle.net/ayb9edLm/

Comment: Please have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613433/attach-keyboard-events-to-html5-canvas

Comment: This should be helpful to your project.
http://playgroundjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving key-related events on a canvas is unreliable at best. Use a parent element of the canvas instead, or even the window, for example:

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    // your code here...
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ayb9edLm)

Also note that you can simplify your code by putting the functions to be run under the keypress events within an object, keyed by their keycode values, like this:

```
var gracz = {
    speedY: 0,
    speedX: 0,
    keydown: {
        '37': function() { gracz.speedX -= 1; }, // left
        '38': function() { gracz.speedY -= 1; }, // up
        '39': function() { gracz.speedX += 1; }, // right
        '40': function() { gracz.speedY += 1; }, // down
        '32': function() { console.log('SPACE'); } // space
    }
};

$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    gracz.keydown[e.which](); 
    console.log(gracz);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ayb9edLm/1/)